# Fun ways to learn japanese

Tags: learning

What are your favorite fun ways to learn Japanese?  (At any level)

Comment: Hello Muhd and welcome to JLU. General questions about learning Japanese with no specific query on the language are considered off-topic for the main site. You can try to check some of the previously asked questions on methods in Meta.